# How to retrieving by JPQL a complex manytomany relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have these Many to Many relationships in my **JPA** entities:

```
public class Request {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<RequestAccount> requestAccounts;
}

public class Account {

    List<RequestAccount> requestAccounts;
    private List<Management> managements;
}

public class Management {
    private String description;
}
```

***The relational entity***

```
public class RequestAccount {

    private Account account;
    private Request request;
}
```

And I have a View ( Html) that the user clicks to see details from each part and I need to have access to this relationship in  this way:

```
  request.requestAccount(x).account.managements(x)
```

I thought about something like this:

```
 SELECT r From Request r INNER JOIN FETCH r.requestAccount ra INNER 
 JOIN  ra.account an INNER JOIN FETCH a.managements
```

Or to make two queries.
But none of this sounded the better approach to me ( or even worked), somebody has an idea to add? 
thank you in advance

Comment: You need a **left** join **fetch**, on each join.

Comment: thanks, but my main problem is to get the whole dependencies that i need using an a reasonable jpql instruction

Comment: Define "reasonable".

Comment: A good approach to get this antity and its dependencies  using Jpql,  less expensive as possible.

Comment: And have you tested and benchmarked this solution? Have you tested and benchmarked other solutions? If not, how can you know if it's reasonable or not?

Comment: JPQL "FETCH JOIN" has no alias. Non-portable

Comment: I got your point @JBNizet, but I was just trying to find here technical possibilities using jpa/hibernate in this case and also somebody's thoughts that had similar experiencias